# Different responses between script and manual execution of instructions using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spyder

I want Selenium to display a table with the maximum of rows. This is possible thanks to a button that allows to change the number of rows in the table.
I have made a script :

```
url = 'http://www.side.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/EXPLOITATION/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_driver)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

#I find the field where I want to execute my query
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("textfield")

#I write the text 
elem.send_keys("photovoltaique")

#I send it
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# I wait until ma page is loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes(url))

#I find the button to change my number of rows
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("icon-arrow-bottom")
#I check the length of my object
print(len(elem))
#I click on the right button
elem[1].click()
```

This code is in a function called `change_rows(url)`.
When I execute the script and call the function, this is what I receive as return :

- from the `print(len(elem))` : 1

When I execute manaully the instructions I get:

- from the `print(len(elem))` : 5

And I need the second element of my object `elem`.

I tried with Firefox and Chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just change the page use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'http://www.side.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/EXPLOITATION/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=<Your driver page>)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

# Find the query field, write text and press Enter
driver.find_element_by_id("textfield").send_keys("photovoltaique", Keys.RETURN)

# Wait and click on 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".taille_page .icon-arrow-bottom "))).click()
# Click on the last one, 50 for this case
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='taille_page']//li[last()]"))).click()
```

To get 5 elements, you need to wait for Javascript and jQuery loading completion:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'http://www.side.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/EXPLOITATION/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=<Your driver page>)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

# Find the query field, write text and press Enter
driver.find_element_by_id("textfield").send_keys("photovoltaique", Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for JavaScript and jQuery loading for completion
wait.until(lambda d: d.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete' && jQuery.active === 0;"))

# Wait for all elements to be visible
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "icon-arrow-bottom")))
print(len(elem))

# Click on the right button
elem[1].click()
```

Comment: css: .taille_page .icon-arrow-bottom found 2
xpath: //div[@class='taille_page'] found 2

As i said, you cannot depend on 2 results and hope the order to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is better formated, executed and safe check code:

```
#I write the text 
textFieldEl = driver.find_element_by_id("textfield")
textFieldEl.send_keys("photovoltaique")

#Pressing search button
searchBtnEl = driver.find_element_by_id("submit-search")
searchBtnEl.click();

# I wait until results table is visible.
resultsEl = driver.find_elelement_by_id("resultats_recherche")
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of(resultsEl))

#I find the button to change my number of rows in header menu
headerPageSizeEl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#criteres_recherche + .navigation .pageSize-container span.icon-arrow-bottom")
headerPageSizeEl.click();

#note: adding wait for dropdown to be present.

# dropdown is now open and we will click 50 elements
showFiftyResultsEl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pageSize-container open')]//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a[text()='50']");
showFiftyResultsEl.click();
```

Comment: Check manually the xpath and you will see there is only 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the dynamic wait for search results. It should print 5 elements now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'http://www.side.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/EXPLOITATION/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=<Your driver page>)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

#I find the field where I want to execute my query
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("textfield")

#I write the text 
elem.send_keys("photovoltaique")

#I send it
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# I wait until ma page is loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'taille_page')))

#I find the button to change my number of rows
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("icon-arrow-bottom")
#I check the length of my object
print(len(elem))
#I click on the right button
elem[1].click()
```